Eslint allow globals while keeping undef errors
In eslint I have to declare each global class
        Combo: "writable",
        Block: "writable",
        Peek: "writable",

Or disable undef "no-undef": "off",
But I'd rather have undef rule.
Thing is I don't want to register each class in the config file.
Is there a middle ground?
